# Skip first item then repeat rule every x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I have a bootstrp grid where wrapping items are varying height I use a rule like below to ensure I have the same number of items on each row.

```
.col-sm-6:nth-child(3),
.col-sm-6:nth-child(5),
.col-sm-6:nth-child(7),
.col-sm-6:nth-child(9) {
  clear: both;
}
```

I know this is not the best way to do it.  If I have a very large grid I would need to specify the clear for every row explicitly doing it like this.

How do I write it as a repeating rule without having to specify the start of each row of wrapping elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.col-sm-6:nth-child(2n + 3) {
  clear: both;
}
```

But I recommend you to use flexbox to avoid `float` and `clear` hacks.

Just add to you container:

```
.some-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```